# I'm getting this EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, eof

I am trying to write a program that returns the count of the maximum number of remaining elements in an array when the sum of the larger elements is greater than a certain number 'w'.

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
sum = 0
count = 0

n, w = [int(x) for x in input(" ").split()]
for i in range(n):
    c = list(int(num) for num in input(" ").strip().split())[:n]
    
b = sorted(c)
for i in reversed(b):
    sum = sum + i
    count = count + 1
    if(sum>=w):
        print(n - count)
        break
    else:
        continue
```

I have tried almost everything but the compiler is still throwing this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./prog.py", line 6, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: What environment are you running this code in - is it some sort of online IDE?  Some of those require that you pre-enter all of the input before running the code; in that case, you're simply calling `input()` more times than there were lines of input provided.  (I suspect the problem is the `for i in range(n)` line: if there are only two lines of data for each problem, there shouldn't be a loop here.)

Comment: Is the code properly indented? Where does the body of the for loop `for i in range(t):` begin and end?